# Squid proxy unable to use LDAP/S on CentOS 6

Tags: active-directory, ldap, squid, tls, certificate-authority

I've configured Squid proxy to authenticate against Active Directory. With plain LDAP, everything works as expected. However, when I try to use LDAP/S, I get these error messages:

```
p11-kit: couldn't stat path: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/MyCA.crt
p11-kit: couldn't stat path: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/..
p11-kit: couldn't stat path: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/.
Could not Activate TLS connection
```

I've installed ca-certificates, ran `update-ca-trust enable`. Copied my CA cert to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors, then ran `update-ca-trust extract`.

I've even tried copying the CA cert to /etc/openldap/certs and ran `cacertdir_rehash /etc/openldap/certs`. But I still can't authenticate properly when using LDAP/S.

The only way I found around this problem was to disable SSL verifications in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf by setting these options:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
TLS_CRLCHECK none
```

With those options, I am able to use LDAP/S and authenticate correctly.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. But please note that SF is a Q&A site, meaning that you should add the solution to your problem as an answer and don't put it into the question. Please see the [help] for more info.

Comment: I didn't think it was a solution, more an explanation of what steps I took to try and resolve the problem. I still do not know ow to fix the issue and am keeping the question open.

Comment: can the squid user read the certificates? the "couldn't stat" errors could mean the files are not readable.